# Как сделать расспознавание нажатия клавиш JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, клавиатура

Я хочу сделать что-то на подобие экранной клавиатуры, но пока смог реализовать запись только при нажатии клавиш на экранной клавиатуре и хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии клавиш на обычной клаве это тоже отображалось...

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     
    <title>Online Keyboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="container">
    <textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    <ul id="keyboard">
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span><span class="on">!</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span><span class="on">@</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span><span class="on">#</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span><span class="on">$</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span><span class="on">%</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span><span class="on">^</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span><span class="on">&amp;</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span><span class="on">*</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span><span class="on">(</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span><span class="on">)</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">-</span><span class="on">_</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">=</span><span class="on">+</span></li>
        <li class="delete lastitem">delete</li>
        <li class="tab">tab</li>
        <li class="letter">q</li>
        <li class="letter">w</li>
        <li class="letter">e</li>
        <li class="letter">r</li>
        <li class="letter">t</li>
        <li class="letter">y</li>
        <li class="letter">u</li>
        <li class="letter">i</li>
        <li class="letter">o</li>
        <li class="letter">p</li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">[</span><span class="on">{</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">]</span><span class="on">}</span></li>
        <li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">\</span><span class="on">|</span></li>
        <li class="capslock">caps lock</li>
        <li class="letter">a</li>
        <li class="letter">s</li>
        <li class="letter">d</li>
        <li class="letter">f</li>
        <li class="letter">g</li>
        <li class="letter">h</li>
        <li class="letter">j</li>
        <li class="letter">k</li>
        <li class="letter">l</li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">;</span><span class="on">:</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">'</span><span class="on">&quot;</span></li>
        <li class="return lastitem">return</li>
        <li class="left-shift">shift</li>
        <li class="letter">z</li>
        <li class="letter">x</li>
        <li class="letter">c</li>
        <li class="letter">v</li>
        <li class="letter">b</li>
        <li class="letter">n</li>
        <li class="letter">m</li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">,</span><span class="on">&lt;</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">.</span><span class="on">&gt;</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">/</span><span class="on">?</span></li>
        <li class="right-shift lastitem">shift</li>
        <li class="space lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var $write = $('#write'),
            shift = false,
            capslock = false;
        
        $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
            
            // Shift keys
            if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
                $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                $('.symbol span').toggle();
                
                shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
                capslock = false;
                return false;
            }
            
            // Caps lock
            if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
                $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                capslock = true;
                return false;
            }
            
            // Delete
            if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
                var html = $write.html();
                
                $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
                return false;
            }
            
            // Special characters
            if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
            if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
            if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
            if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";
            
            // Uppercase letter
            if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();
            
            // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
            if (shift === true) {
                $('.symbol span').toggle();
                if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                
                shift = false;
            }
            
            // Add the character
            $write.html($write.html() + character);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font: 71%/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    background: #eee;
}

#container {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 688px;
}

#write {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 671px;
    height: 200px;
    font: 1em/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#keyboard {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#keyboard li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.capslock, .tab, .left-shift {
    clear: left;
}

#keyboard .tab, #keyboard .delete {
    width: 70px;
}

#keyboard .capslock {
    width: 80px;
}

#keyboard .return {
    width: 77px;
}

#keyboard .left-shift {
    width: 95px;
}

#keyboard .right-shift {
    width: 109px;
}

.lastitem {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#keyboard .space {
    clear: left;
    width: 681px;
}

.on {
    display: none;
}

#keyboard li:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
    -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Задачи *на подобие* треугольников.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     
    <title>Online Keyboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="container">
    <textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    <ul id="keyboard">
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span><span class="on">!</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span><span class="on">@</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span><span class="on">#</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span><span class="on">$</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span><span class="on">%</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span><span class="on">^</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span><span class="on">&amp;</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span><span class="on">*</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span><span class="on">(</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span><span class="on">)</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">-</span><span class="on">_</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">=</span><span class="on">+</span></li>
        <li class="delete lastitem">delete</li>
        <li class="tab">tab</li>
        <li class="letter">q</li>
        <li class="letter">w</li>
        <li class="letter">e</li>
        <li class="letter">r</li>
        <li class="letter">t</li>
        <li class="letter">y</li>
        <li class="letter">u</li>
        <li class="letter">i</li>
        <li class="letter">o</li>
        <li class="letter">p</li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">[</span><span class="on">{</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">]</span><span class="on">}</span></li>
        <li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">\</span><span class="on">|</span></li>
        <li class="capslock">caps lock</li>
        <li class="letter">a</li>
        <li class="letter">s</li>
        <li class="letter">d</li>
        <li class="letter">f</li>
        <li class="letter">g</li>
        <li class="letter">h</li>
        <li class="letter">j</li>
        <li class="letter">k</li>
        <li class="letter">l</li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">;</span><span class="on">:</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">'</span><span class="on">&quot;</span></li>
        <li class="return lastitem">return</li>
        <li class="left-shift">shift</li>
        <li class="letter">z</li>
        <li class="letter">x</li>
        <li class="letter">c</li>
        <li class="letter">v</li>
        <li class="letter">b</li>
        <li class="letter">n</li>
        <li class="letter">m</li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">,</span><span class="on">&lt;</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">.</span><span class="on">&gt;</span></li>
        <li class="symbol"><span class="off">/</span><span class="on">?</span></li>
        <li class="right-shift lastitem">shift</li>
        <li class="space lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
    $(function(){
        var $write = $('#write'),
            shift = false,
            capslock = false;

        // Обработка нажатия клавиш физической клавиатуры:
        document.onkeypress = function(e){
             $write.html($write.html() + e.key);
        }

        $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
            
            // Shift keys
            if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
                $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                $('.symbol span').toggle();
                
                shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
                capslock = false;
                return false;
            }
            
            // Caps lock
            if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
                $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                capslock = true;
                return false;
            }
            
            // Delete
            if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
                var html = $write.html();
                
                $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
                return false;
            }
            
            // Special characters
            if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
            if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
            if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
            if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";
            
            // Uppercase letter
            if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();
            
            // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
            if (shift === true) {
                $('.symbol span').toggle();
                if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                
                shift = false;
            }
            
            // Add the character
            $write.html($write.html() + character);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не сработало.....

Comment: @dudha369, Странно, у меня все работает.  Проверил на Файерфоксе, Яндексе и Хроме.